# Difference in calculating middle index of array?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, average, quicksort

I have been trying to solve QuickSort and I got thru a scenario where we are selecting pivot element as the middle one.

http://www.java2novice.com/java-sorting-algorithms/quick-sort/

```
 // calculate pivot number, I am taking pivot as middle index number
        int pivot = array[lowerIndex+(higherIndex-lowerIndex)/2];
```

How difference this is with the below way to get the middle index?

```
        int pivot = array[(lowerIndex+higherIndex)/2];
```

I remember I have seen this many times before also. And I am sure I am missing a scenario where this helpful when we get a odd number or something.

I tried few sample values but I get the same response for both ways. 
What am I missing?

Thanks for your respone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is more likely that

> (lowerIndex+higherIndex)/2

overflows rather than

> lowerIndex+(higherIndex-lowerIndex)/2.

For example for `lowerIndex == higherIndex == Integer.MAX_VALUE / 2 + 1`.

## Edit:

#### Mathematical proof of equivalence of the expressions

```
l + (r - l)/2                            (in java notation)
  = l + round_towards_zero((r - l) / 2)  (in math notation)
  = round_towards_zero(l + (r - l) / 2)  (since l is an integer)
  = round_towards_zero((2 * l + r - l) / 2)
  = round_towards_zero(r + l) / 2)
  = (l + r) / 2                          (in java notation)
```

Comment: Ok got it! So overflow is the reason. I remember i have read it long  before somewhere but couldn't recollect it. Thanks

Comment: @Nicky Yep, I added a mathematical proof of their equivalence in regular algebra.

Comment: @Nicky Btw as a curiosity, the Java standard library was using the "buggy" version with the overflow in its binary search method. The bug went undiscovered for years till Google ran it at scale and found it. See this post by Joshua Bloch: https://research.googleblog.com/2006/06/extra-extra-read-all-about-it-nearly.html

Comment: How about doing like this (r/2)+(l/2) ? I tried compiling it and decompiling doesn't make the statement as (r+l)/2 . So is this way not correct? It will calculate r/2 first and then (l/2) . So ...??

Comment: In order for overflow to occur with 32 bit signed integers, both indexes would have to be >= 1GB (2^30). This could be possible with an array of characters, or perhaps an array of 16 bit integers, but for an array of 32 bit integers, most 32 bit systems can't do a single allocation for an array that large.

Comment: @Nicky that's not correct because for example for `l == r == 1`, you have `l / 2 == r / 2 == 0` but `(l + r) / 2 == 1`. The issue is that java rounds towards 0 (similar to a floor function on positive integers). Java's division is not like in calculus

Comment: @rcgldr Tested on my macbook with a 64-bit JVM allocating >2^30 integers and the allocation was fine (requires -Xmx). I would expect most JVM's to be 64 bits nowadays.

Comment: @rcgldr Indices must be 32-bit integers by the Java Language Specification. "64 bits" refers to the size of object references in the runtime. This doesn't apply to arrays and, even if it did, it wouldn't be allowed by the JLS.

Comment: @GilVegliach - I wasn't aware that 64 bit java limits indexes to 31 bits (32 bit signed integer, negative indexes not allowed). I assume this limits array size to 2^31 elements? So unlike C / C++ or most other languages, java doesn't fully benefit from the larger address space of 64 bit mode?

Comment: @rcgldr Not for arrays but the whole heap can be larger than 4 GB.

Comment: @rcgldr Actually, thinking about it, what if you have code like `int len = arr.length`. You cannot make this 64 bit because it would alter the logic of pre-existing code (e.g. wrt overflows). I guess this was the reason why only object references became wider: their width is transparent to the code.

Comment: @GilVegliach - which is why C / C++ has a `size_t` type for indexes, which typically is a 32 bit unsigned integer in 32 bit mode and a 64 bit unsigned integer in 64 bit mode.